# How do you escape double quote and html tags in form elements using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

HTML:

```
Input: <span id="form"></span>
```

JavaScript:

```
var title = 'inside "<h1>outside?</h1>';
var inserted_data = '<input type="text" value=' + title + '>';
$("#form").html(inserted_data);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/uk7h8sw7/

The results are weird. `inside` is in the form field, while `outside` is outside it. And the tags are missing almost entirely.

How do I escape the double quote and HTML tags so it doesn't screw up like this?

Comment: Why does the title have one double quote and a question mark?

Comment: I'm trying to prepare for users inputting weird things like that. Currently if a user inputs a single double quote, and then when I display the form where they inputted it, things go weird like this.

Comment: Basically you want to remove any HTML tags and display just text, correct?

Comment: I like your approach, but Arvind has the easier answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed quotes for the `value` attribute:

```
value=' + title + '
```

Use this instead:

```
 value=\'' + title + '\'
```

```js
var title = 'inside "<h1>outside?</h1>';
var inserted_data = '<input type="text" value=\'' + title + '\'/>';
$("#form").html(inserted_data);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Input: <span id="form"></span>
```

A more appropriate solution is:

```js
var titles = ['inside "<h1>outside?</h1>', 'inside\'>out'];

$.each(titles, function(_, title) {
  $('<input>').prop({
    'type': 'text',
    'value': title
  }).appendTo('#form');
});
```

```css
input {
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Input: <span id="form"></span>
```

Comment: This is really helpful, but now I found it doesn't work if my title is this: `var title = 'inside\'>out';`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`jQuery(html, attributes)`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery-html-attributes)

```js
var title = 'inside "<h1>outside?</h1>';
var inserted_data = $("<input>", {
                      type:"text",
                      value:title
                    });
$("#form").html(inserted_data);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
Input: <span id="form"></span>
```